# How to make this function run multiple times on the click of the button that is in index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**JS CODE**

```
var heading = document.querySelector('#heading');
var btn = document.querySelector('#change_theme');
var body = document.querySelector('body');

function changeTheme() {
    var getBGColor = () => {
        return window.getComputedStyle(body).backgroundColor;
    }

    if (getBGColor() === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
        body.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
        btn.style.backgroundColor = '#00a9ff';
        btn.style.border = '2px solid #0026ff';
        heading.style.color = '#fff';
    }

    else {
        body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        heading.style.color = '#000';
    }
}
```

The above js code only works only 2 times. But I want to execute it as many times as the button is clicked. Please tell me how to do that...

Comment: can you give it in code snippet?

Comment: where is your `onClick` listener?

Comment: Toggle a class..... So simple and easy to update in a CSS file.

Comment: You do not remove the properties you set in the first if.... So the button will stay the way you set it. It has no clue you want it to revert.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```js
var heading = document.querySelector('#heading');
var btn = document.querySelector('#change_theme');
var body = document.querySelector('body');

function changeTheme() {
  var getBGColor = () => {
    return window.getComputedStyle(body).backgroundColor;
  }
  console.log(getBGColor());

  if (getBGColor() === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
    btn.style.backgroundColor = '#00a9ff';
    btn.style.border = '2px solid #0026ff';
    heading.style.color = '#fff';
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    heading.style.color = '#000';
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="heading">
    <button id="change_theme" onclick="changeTheme()">
      Change Theme
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note if you click on `<>` in question editor can create a Stack Snippet that runs here in the page

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra logic to your if statement.

```
if(getBGColor() === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' || getBGColor() === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
```

Here i've just tried to recreate the issue. It may help.

```js
const heading = document.querySelector('#heading');
const btn = document.querySelector('#change_theme');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const getBGColor = () => {
  return window.getComputedStyle(body).backgroundColor;
}
const toggleData = {
  toggle: {bodyBGColor: '#000', btnBGColor: '#0026ff', btnBorder: '2px solid #00a9ff', headingColor: '#fff'},
  original: {bodyBGColor: '#fff', btnBGColor: '#00a9ff', btnBorder: '2px solid #0026ff', headingColor: '#000'}
}

const {original, toggle} = toggleData;

btn.addEventListener('click', toggleTheme)

function toggleTheme() {
  const bodyBackgroundColor = getBGColor();

  if(bodyBackgroundColor === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' || bodyBackgroundColor === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
    body.style.backgroundColor = toggle.bodyBGColor;
    btn.style.backgroundColor = toggle.btnBGColor;
    btn.style.border = toggle.btnBorder;
    heading.style.color = toggle.headingColor;
  } else {
      body.style.backgroundColor = original.bodyBGColor;
      btn.style.backgroundColor = original.btnBGColor;
      btn.style.border = original.btnBorder;
      heading.style.color = original.headingColor;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2 id="heading">Heading</h2>
  <button id="change_theme">Change theme</button>

</body>
</html>
```